# Edit or Remove BreezeJS EntityManager Once Instance Reference Lost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm constructing a CRM application with a SPA structure, using **BreezeJS** and **AngularJS**, and I'm utilizing a dynamically-generated tabbed environment to display what I'll refer to here on out as **modules**. When a user clicks a side menu item, a new tab is created, and an HTML template (**aka module**) is loaded into the new content area. While some of the module types are to be opened only once at a time (a grid of **Accounts**), others, such as an **Account Editor** module, can be opened many times. That way, the user can modify many accounts at any given time throughout the day, but always be doing so from a single **Accounts** grid instance.

So far, I have a working system for the Account Editor module, in that I create a master `Breeze EntityManager` with appropriate configuration parameters (service name, save options, etc.) and then make a copy of it any time a new Account Editor is created, using **`masterManager.createEmptyCopy()`** (as per the code outlined at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers#CreateMultipleManagers):

```
var serviceName = "/breeze/accounts";

var ds = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: serviceName,
    hasServerMetadata: true
});

var masterManager = new breeze.EntityManager({
               dataService: ds,
               saveOptions: new breeze.SaveOptions({ allowConcurrentSaves: false })
           });

function createManagerCopy() {
    // same configuration as master; no entities in cache.
    var sandboxManager = masterManager.createEmptyCopy();
    return sandboxManager;
}
```

Then, I call an `EntityQuery`, by passing in the copied `EntityManager` and entity `Id (key)`, in order to get the appropriate Account and populate each open editor with apparently all the benefits of Breeze.

```
function queryAccountByKey(mgr, key) {
    var keyPredicate = breeze.Predicate.create('id', 'eq', key);
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery('AccountsBase')
                          .expand('ContactsBase')
                          .where(keyPredicate);

    var promise = mgr.executeQuery(query)
                     .catch(queryFailed);

    return promise;

    function queryFailed(error) {
        console.log('Query Account by Id Failed', error);
        return $q.reject(error); // so downstream promise users know it failed
    }
}
```

There does not appear to be any conflict with the other open editors and their respective entity managers, *so long I maintain the copied* `EntityManager` *in the module's Angular* `scope`. Editing and saving this way is, well…a breeze! :P *(sorry)*

**The problem I’m having** is when I switch to another Angular `route`, such as a login screen, and then come back to the home screen. Due to the complexities of each tabbed module, any **Account Editor** module I had opened before the routing took place must be reloaded from stored settings (even if the layout is stored in the cache). However, then there are two Breeze entity managers handling that account. **The effect is that saving changes for a single Account Editor now commits twice** (or however many times you’ve gone away and back from the home layout).

**What I’m trying to figure out is how to get access to a specific** `EntityManager` **instance, from the client, once I navigate back to the home layout and the original instance reference (in the scope, in my case) is lost**.  In other words, is there an `EntityManager` *collection* that I can query to reuse or delete an instance? If I can grab a manager instance by name or other Id, I can simply reassign it to my scope without removing and recreating it.

In the event that I do need to remove the `EntityManager`, I can’t find anything anywhere to describe implementing something like a `destroy()` method…just a `clear()` method, which only clears the entities and does not remove the `EntityManager` from the client. Of course, if I'm going about this all wrong, please advise as to a better approach. Hopefully I've explained things clearly enough that someone can lend a possible solution.

**SOLUTION**

So, thanks to PW Kad's answer, I was able to reuse the entity managers instead of deleting and re-creating them, by adding them to an empty object collection on the $rootScope when they're initialized (still using the `createEmptyCopy()` method outlined above). This allows for access throughout the Angular app, without polluting the global namespace. I had already implemented a unique `ID` to be associated with each tab - and thus the modules in the content areas - so I appended that ID to create a name, such as `'EM_' + instanceId`, for storage in the `$rootScope.entityManagers` object. Later, I can retrieve the `EntityManager` instance in the `$rootScope`, using this ID, which is found in each **Account Editor**'s Angular `Controller`.

Here's the new code:

```
// NEW: Add an 'entityManagers' object to the $rootScope of my main app module
angular.module('app', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.entityManagers = {};
    $rootScope.entityManagers.count = 0;
}]);

// In the dataServices factory for the main app module
var serviceName = "/breeze/accounts";

var ds = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: serviceName,
    hasServerMetadata: true
});

var masterManager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    dataService: ds,
    saveOptions: new breeze.SaveOptions({ allowConcurrentSaves: false })
});

function createManager(instanceId) {
    // make a copy of the above EntityManager (with no cached entities)
    var sandboxManager = masterManager.createEmptyCopy();

    // NEW: Save the EntityManager instance to the $rootScope
    $rootScope.entityManagers['EM_' + instanceId] = sandboxManager;
    $rootScope.entityManagers.count++;

    return sandboxManager;
}

// In the event that you want to delete the EntityManager from the $rootScope
function deleteManager(instanceId) {
    var manager = $rootScope.entityManagers['EM_' + instanceId];
    manager.clear();
    delete $rootScope.entityManagers['EM_' + instanceId];
    $rootScope.entityManagers.count--;
}

// And lastly, inside any Angular controller
$scope.instanceId = '1234'; // Dynamically-assigned at runtime

$scope.init = function() {
    var manager = $rootScope.entityManagers['EM_' + $scope.instanceId];
    if (manager === undefined) {
       $scope.entityManager = 
              entityManagerService.createManager($scope.instanceId);
    } else {
       $scope.entityManager = manager;
    }
}

$scope.getEntityById = function(id){
    //use $scope.entityManager here to query database via Breeze
}
```

While I would still like to know where BreezeJS keeps its `EntityManager` collection, I have a valid solution. I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a poor design choice to reinstantiate a new entity manager every time you change pages as in effect you are losing the caching mechanism and sharing the entities across pages but if you must do so you can always do so fairly trivially with something like -

```
var manager = {};

manager = manager ? manager.clear() : new breeze.EntityManager();
```

or

```
manager = manager ? (function () { delete manager; return new breeze.EntityManager(); })() : new breeze.EntityManager();
```

or many other ways really.

I would recommend not doing that though and just doing something like this -

```
var manager = {};

// Some route activation logic
if (!manager) {
    manager = new breeze.EntityManager();
}
```

**Edit**

Well the short answer is I am not 100% sure how the breeze object in the global namespace is referencing the entity manager.  I don't think there is a collection of entity managers that the breeze object keeps, but I may be wrong.  I don't see why calling delete on the entity manager isn't working but this should do what you are trying to do -

Somewhere in either one of your closures or in the global namespace create an object called entityManagers.  Example -

```
window.entityManagers = {};
window.entityManagers.count = 0;
```

Then tack the manager while it is created onto that namespace.  There is probably a more dynamic way to do this just giving some pseudo-code -

```
window.entityManagers.createNewManager = function (name) {
    window.entityManagers[name] = new breeze.EntityManager();
}


window.entityManagers.createNewManager('ManagerNumber1');
```

And then when you want to dispose of a specific instance just clear it then delete it.  Get the instance you want either by a variable reference or if you can't do that for some crazy reason just grab it off the affected entity -

```
window.entityManagers.deleteManager = function (name) {
    window.entityManagers[name].clear();
    delete window.entityManagers[name];
}

window.entityManagers.deleteManager('ManagerNumber1');
```

For all intents and purposes, as long as there no other references to that instance of the manager in other modules / controllers / whatever than this *should* delete the entityManager from the world.  I still don't fully understand the use case so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The following link is from IdeaBlade: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers#CreateMultipleManagers, which explains that my methodology (which I took directly from them) is acceptable for very complex situations, such as the one I'm working with.

Comment: @AaronJessen Understood, but from your question I am gathering that the problem is having the same entity in two separate managers' caches - is that correct?  I also gather that you are creating new entity managers when the route is activated each time.  I don't understand why you wouldn't simply create them each one time at the beginning and then begin to fill their cache as needed.  It's very possible I don't understand what problem you are incurring

Comment: You're correct in that new entity managers are being created upon route changes. Using the UI-router for Angular (or the $routeProvider method) is causing the HTML templates (modules) to change out completely. So far, I haven't been able to create and persist the entities in the entity managers and then retrieve them upon returning to the main page, but that could be from my inexperience and thus warrants another question. But for now, I would like to put to bed whether you can delete entity managers or not.

Comment: If you aren't able to tell me how to delete `EntityManager` instances, can you at least tell me how to grab a specific instance of one, after it has been instantiated and after there is no longer a variable that points to it, such as an Angular scope?

Comment: So if I understand what you are trying to do fully I don't quite understand why `delete manager;` wouldn't work.  For clarification I am not saying put the manager in an array and `remove` it.  I will clarify that point in the answer with code that will actually do it : )

Comment: The code sample is much appreciated. I've implemented a flavor of your solution, which saves the entity managers to an object on Angular's $rootScope (giving me access throughout the app without polluting the global namespace). The clear/delete process you provided works, but it's a non-issue, now that I can retain entity managers despite routing changes (I preferred to reuse them instead of deleting them anyway, so kudos). Even though I'd still like to know where BreezeJS keeps its collection of entity managers, this workaround is quite sufficient for my needs. Thanks a million!